# Overloading postfix increment operator

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the postfix increment operator as a member function for a class which stores large numbers as an array of ints. But it keeps getting returned as 0. Any tips on why this doesn't work?

This is a homework question, so I would like more of a tip than straight code. Thanks.

The member data looks like:

```
largeInt = new int[maxSize];
int maxSize, currentSize;
```

Where currentSize is a tracking variable used to keep track of how big the array currently is.

And my code is:

The Load function puts an int at the first spot in the array and shifts everything else over.

```
/* postfix*/
NewInt& NewInt::operator++(int nothing)
{   
    int count = 1;
    largeInt[currentSize - count] += 1;
    while(largeInt[currentSize - count] > 9)
    {
            if(currentSize - count - 1 < 0)
            {
                    firstVar = true;
                    Load(1);
            }
            else    
                    largeInt[currentSize - count - 1] += 1;

            count++;              
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: you show LargeInt but the actual code uses 'number'. Is number a reference to LargeInt

Comment: don't name the parameter of operator++; that's a best practise

Comment: yeah I changed it to largeInt, it is correct in my program, just a little tired, copied and pasted from a test program. fixed.

Comment: Chubsdad means the parameter named "nothing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment disagrees with your code. `operator++(int)` is postfix increment, `operator++()` is prefix.

Comment: Oops, well I need to do both of them anyway. I'll edit it to postfix

Comment: At least partially. Doing, 99++ gives 110.

Comment: I was getting hung up on that pre/postfix. Figured the other stuff out. Thanks.